# I have an array that has 10 values, however somewhere along my code one of the values changes?

Tags: java, arrays, debugging

I'm currently debugging the code using the eclipse IDE and trying to figure out where this change takes place. Is there anyway I can set my debugger to expect an array of certain values and then show where or why one of the values is not what it is expected to be? Or any other tips on how I could narrow this down

Comment: Show the code, create a [mcve]. Tell us which IDE (or more precise which debugger) you use. Make an example, explain the whole situation in more detail. In the current state nobody can form an adequate answer as defined by [answer]. Please read [ask], thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use a fairly up to date version of eclipse:
You can write a getter and wrap all access to the array through that getter, assuming that you have modifying access to all accessing calls.
However since an array is strictly speaking an object of its own, methods can pass references on the array at any point in the code, which makes it impossible to entirely catch all possible access.
Furthermore, even the singular objects within the array can be referenced anywhere, so they might be modified on their own.

To debug this, first isolate, whether an object is replaced within the array, or if a value within an object changes.
If the first is the case, then you must chase after the array itself, as described.
If the second is the case, then you can set a "watchpoint" on the attribute within the object that changes. Also, if the value always changes in the same way (for example to the same value) you can set that as condition in the breakpoint (right click on the point and go to "Breakpoint properties". Then check the checkbox "conditional" and enter your condition in the box below.